# how to get auto filled values in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get auto filled values at page load. 
I have tried to get password field value at window load function.
But it returns empty.
How and when will i get auto filled value of input field in javascript.
Please help me to resolve this.

```
$(window).load(function () {    
if ($(".username").val() !== "" || $(".password").val() !== "") {
   alert("test");
}
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: please update your question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

try document ready method instead of window load

Comment: Added my code. in this case, by opening console and while debug username can able to get but password value not returning anything.